# What do you call the style used for images like this?

Tags: vector, style-identification

Can anyone tell me the name of the style for images like this?

[image]

[Link on Vecteezy](https://www.vecteezy.com/vector-art/1311716-business-people-elegant-in-the-workplace)

Comment: No name. call it what you may. "Flat vector illustration" is a good description. This is by the way a general problem, you cant have a name for everything. Its serious stuff so if you can demonstrate even a plausible solution this then i can get you a billion funding no questions asked. Problem is that if something has a name then others need to know the name for it to be useful. But if you have 10,000,000 items how do you make sure people agree on the name. If you take 10 seconds to memorize the name it takes 100 million seconds to do it would take 3 years or a  full bachelors degree to do.

Comment: "corporate memphis without insane proportions" maybe? I've seen that term thrown around a bit.